# how to have two controller actions, one shared view for Zend_Controller_Action Class?

Tags: zend-framework, view, controller

How do you specify a custom view script for a given Controller Action method?

For example:

```
Class UserGalleryController extends Zend_Controller_Action 
{

 public function fooAction()
 {
  $this->view->actionMsg = 'foo';
  // (uses foo.phtml automagically)
 }

 public function  barAction()
 {
  $this->view->actionMsg = 'bar';
  //use foo's view script ?????
 }
}

I basically want to have one view script (foo.phtml)
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function barAction()
{
    $this->view->actionMsg = 'bar';
    $this->render('foo');
}
```